# Batch combine large CSV files and remove repeating header

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to combine several large csv files with identical fields.  The best I've been able to do is:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set first=1
for %%F in (*.csv) do (
  if defined first (
    type "%%F" >> new.csv
    set "first="
  ) else (
    more +1 "%%F" >> new.csv
  )
)
```

This works great on small files, but the more command gets stuck at the end of each screen dump when the files are larger.

Try as I might, I haven't been able to get more to run straight through the entire file when writing it to new.csv - can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET first=y
SET newfile=new.csv
for %%F in (*.csv) do IF NOT %%F==%newfile% (
  if defined first (
    COPY /y "%%F" %newfile% >nul
    set "first="
  ) else (
    FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%i IN (%%F) DO >> %newfile% ECHO %%i
  )
)
```

*Edit*
To support blank lines in a CSV you can replace the inner FOR with:
    `for /f "skip=1 tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" %%F') do >> %newfile% echo.%%j`

Comment: +1. You should `echo.%%i` instead of just `echo %%i`, in case a csv has a blank line. You don't want `ECHO is off.` appearing in the new file.

Comment: @azhrei - FOR /F skips blank lines, so they should never be a problem.

Comment: Your code will be more efficient (faster) if you move the `>> %newfile%` to after the closing parenthesis for the ELSE block

Comment: @dbenham - Thanks. I was writing an answer and came up against that echo problem. Not sure what's going on there exactly. Regardless, CSV's can have significant blank lines, so skipping blank lines is problematic.

Comment: @dbenham for /f bypasses *completely* blank lines, but retains lines with whitespace. Echo needs some non whitespace.

Comment: @azhrei - yes, good point. Lines with spaces are not skipped.

Comment: And don't forget the setlocal and endlocal to keep the variables local and environment clean.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach:

1. Concatenate all the files using copy, which is nice and fast, into a
   temporary file.
2. Read the header line.
3. Write the header into the output file.
4. Write any line that doesn't match the header into the output file.
5. Delete the temporary file.

There is a cost in having to copy the file twice, but the parsing is using simple functions that should be fast to run.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set output=new.csv
set temp=temp.csv
copy *.csv %temp%
set /p header=<%temp%
echo %header%>%output%
findstr /v /C:"%header%" %temp%>>%output%
del %temp%
endlocal
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

After cd'ing into the directory that has the .csvs:

awk 'FNR<=4 && NR>4{next;}{print}' `find . -type f -name '*.csv'` > combined.csv

Here I have assumed that every csv has 4 header lines, but you can substitute with whatever number you want.