# How do I merge multiple txt files with different file names in to one txt file, successfully?

Tags: batch-file

**Scenario:**
During the day, several txt files are created in a specific folder on the network.  These txt files are all different names.  A batch file will then run which combines all the txt files in to one master txt file.

**What I've done so far:**
The closest I've gotten to accomplishing this is by running a batch file in the same network folder which contains the following script

```
copy /b *.txt IMPORT.txt
```

**The Problem:**
The "IMPORT.txt" file will not successfully add the contents of each file directly beneath the previous data.  It will sometimes just add it to the last word in the previous data set.

Example:

File 1 is named "n5z.txt"
The contents of that file are

```
John, Doe
```

File 2 is named "po6.txt"
The contents of that file are

```
Jane, Doe
George, Washington
```

File 3 is named "xyz.txt"
The contents of that file are

```
John, Adams
Betty, White
Tom, Petty
Chris, White
```

Then I open the Windows Batch file (.bat) located in the same folder which runs the following script

```
copy /b *.txt IMPORT.txt
```

The ending result is a file named "IMPORT.txt"
The contents of this file looks like this

```
John, DoeJane, Doe
George, WashingtonJohn, Adams
Betty, White
Tom, Petty
Chris, White
```

I need it to look like this

```
John, Doe
Jane, Doe
George, Washington
John, Adams
Betty, White
Tom, Petty
Chris, White
```

Comment: What does "add it to the last word" mean in this context? Are you free to choose different filenames so that `IMPORT.txt` is not caught by the `*.txt` wildcard?

Comment: By "batch" I'm assuming you are referring to a Windows .bat file. What other scripting languages/tools are available to use? Can you use powershell?

Comment: @CRDrost I think he means that the previous file has no ending linefeed so the first line of one file is on the same line as the end of the previous file.

Comment: Similar to what @CRDrost asked, what kind of line endings do you have? Are they all consistent? Or do some files end with a blank line and others do not?

Comment: @CR Drost - I've added an example of what I'm trying to do I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=q45178448*.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%filename1%" '
 ) DO (
 TYPE "%sourcedir%\%%a"
 ECHO.
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used some files named `q45178448*.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing. You would need to enter your required filemask to replace this value.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

The problem appears to be that the `.txt` files generated do not have a terminal newline, so this procedure simply generates a list of the required files in memory, serially `type`s then to the destination with a newline inserted after each by the `echo`.

--edit 201708041820

`sourcedir` should **not** be in `filename1` - only worked because I'd used `.` for `sourcedir`.

Comment: Hi @Magoo - My files are random and don't have a consistent file name.  I took a wild guess and just stripped the "'q45178448'" leaving just the "'*.txt'".  Unfortunately I just got a blank text file.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd missed pasting the closing `"` in the `dir` line - your change is quite correct - `*.txt` means "all `.txt` files. I use `q????????` to refer to SO question numbers so I can locate the required code and data should any problems arise. I normally cut-and-paste the code directly from my batch, so I'm astounded that the quote disappeared. Can happen sometimes I suppose. If you copy the `dir` line without the enclosing *single*-quotes directly before the first `(` line, then you should get a listing of the files found to the console.

Comment: IT WORKED! BEAUTIFUL!!  This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Wait a minute.  The output file has a blank line at the top.  Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: You would get a blank line at the top of the file if the first file matching the mask was empty or started with a control-Z character - in fact any such file would give rise to a blank line. I can't see your files so that's in your bailiwick. You could change the `echo.` to `if %%~za neq 0 echo.` which would **not** generate the blank line if the file had zero length.

Comment: Okay, I see what's happening, I modified the file in a way where the the Output file was located in the same directory as the files that I'm merging in to that Output file.  As soon as I specified a different directory for the output file, it no longer generated the blank line.

Comment: In theory, Should this work for CSV files too?  I just need to change the file extension right?  I ask because I tried it today and it seemed to duplicate many of the files I was trying to merge.  Mind you, I was also attempting this  by placing the output file in the same directory.  I'm going to mark this question answered but if you can get back to me regarding the CSV question I would appreciate it.  Thank you sooo much!!!

Comment: sorry forgot to address you directly regarding my question above.

Comment: Perhaps you could delete the `outfile` to prevent prior versions being included in the process, then output to `outfile`.new to ensure the new file isn't included either, then rename `outfile`.new to `outfile`.

Comment: In theory, it should work for `.csv` files **but** the header would be duplicated for each file encountered. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236025/batch-combine-csvs-remove-header/15236358#15236358 would be a solution.

Comment: Any comment made on a response is notified to the respondent, and any response or comment to OP, so it's not ordinarily required to address either. You do need to address the author of a comment if you wish - or to draw someone else's attention to the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Going back to my initial issue though, it looks as though I'm unable to specify a specific source and destination directory.  If I attempt to do so, it just creates an empty file.  Note, I need to be able to run this batch file from outside the folder where all the txt files are located.  Do I need to do something different?

Comment: Any luck with answering my last question?

Comment: Got a little lost in events, I'm afraid. I believe the edit I've made will fix any problem with this routine.

Comment: GENIUS!  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

## Try the Bash-for-Windows stuff

This is a really straightforward problem for anyone on Linux, where you would just write,

```
ls *.txt | xargs awk 1 >IMPORT.txt
```

Fortunately, those tools are now available on the Windows 10 command line, so just try that and see if it works?

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this out, however I work with clients who aren't always on the most recent version of Windows.  Although I'm sure this works for instances where they're on Windows 10 I would still like to figure out a way to accomplish this where it's not version specific.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I do not, and I could not research it more efficiently than you can.