# Process txt files list

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, txt

I have 5 .txt files with the following name:

PalOrd(numbers).csv

Normally what we do is to rename each file so then an app takes the information to process:

(Bat file) `rename * PalOrd.csv`

Since this process takes too long (as you need to repeat this for every file), I was wondering which code should I add to the one existing in order to:

*If only 1 file exists in that directory, then rename to PalOrd. *If more than 1, copy all of them to have only one PalOrd file and delete the rest (normally we solved this with `copy * PalOrd.csv \B` but we still have the files remaining that need to be deleted manually

Thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps [Batch combine large CSV files and remove repeating header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15236358/2128947) would assist?

Comment: In future, please use the [Edit] facility, insead of deleting [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76009789) then reposting a modification of it. The code you have submitted here, ```copy * PalOrd.csv \B```, is still not using correct syntax.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.